# Do Blupees drop more money if you do more damage to them?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

At the beginning of the game, whenever I saw a Blupee and shot it with my Bokoblin bow, I recall that it would drop a couple of low-value rupees (green and blue, mostly). Now that I've played for a bit, I'm using a Savage Lynel Bow that does 40 damage per arrow - nearly 4 times the damage of my beginner bows. I've also noticed that the Rupee drops from the Blupees seem higher - now I get blues, reds, and even purples sometimes.

Does a higher damage bow make the Blupees drop more Rupees, or is this just confirmation bias on my part? Or perhaps they simply drop more Rupees as the game progresses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on what I can find, it seems like the amounts the Blupees drop is random, but has a lot of variance. Thus, the amount of damage you would deal to them is not a factor in how much they drop.

From [IGN](http://m.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/How_to_Make_Money_%28Rupees%29):

> These are officially known as Blupees, and hitting one with an arrow will cause it to drop quite a few Rupees. The amounts vary wildly, but you could come away with 100 or more with just one shot.

Additionally, from [this article](https://nowloading.co/p/how-to-catch-blupee-rabbit-breath-of-the-wild/4222341):

> The amount of rupees that blupees leave behind varies, but you can expect between 20 - 100 rupees, with occasional exceptions.

Lastly, from [Twinfinite](http://twinfinite.net/2017/03/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-blue-rabbits-what-do-why-you-should-care/):

> The amount of rupees that Blupees leave behind them is random, but you can almost always expect at least 100 rupees from our experiences with them.

Comment: If you are stealthy enough to sneak up behind one, you can stasis it and get in a few direct weapon hits.  This doesn't seem to result in higher denominations, but it does increase the number of drops.  I've gotten a couple hundred rupees at a time this way.

Comment: One thing to take into account is that chaining bow shots on a single Blupee seems to improve the odds. That's just personal observation though.